# Directing file downloads to different folders based on file type

Tags: windows-10, download, automation

Is there a native solution for windows 10 to cause downloads to automatically go into folders based on their file type? For example all files that are applications are directed to a folder called programs. I'm not sure where to start looking into this so I don't have a lot to go on.

Answer (score 0):

I just put together this PowerShell script:

```
$places = @{txt='?\Documents\TextFiles'; exe='?\Documents\NewApps'}

$userprof = [Environment]::ExpandEnvironmentVariables('%USERPROFILE%')
cd ($userprof + '\Downloads')
Do {
  dir -File | % {
    If ($_.Extension.Length -gt 0) {
      $ext = $_.Extension.Substring(1).ToLowerInvariant()
    } Else {
      $ext = 'NOEXT'
    }
    If (-not $places.ContainsKey($ext)) {$ext = 'DEFAULT'}
    If ($places.ContainsKey($ext)) {
      $dest = $places[$ext].Replace('?', $userprof)
      move $_ -Dest $dest
    }
  }
  Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
} While ($true)
```

Save it as a `.ps1` file somewhere.

It's designed to run in the background, checking for new files in your Downloads folder every five seconds. (You can change the interval on the second-to-last line.) To set where the files go, you can change the `$places` map on the first line. A question mark will automatically be replaced with the path to your user profile folder. Currently, it will put `.txt` files in a folder called `TextFiles` under my Documents folder and `.exe` files in one called `NewApps`. You'll need to create those folders before running the script. To set where extensionless files go, add an entry for `NOEXT`. To set where unknown file types go, add an entry for `DEFAULT`.

Before PowerShell will let you run scripts, you'll need to enable script execution. See the "Enabling Scripts" section of [the PowerShell tag wiki](https://superuser.com/tags/powershell/info).

Once that's done, you can set up a normal batch file to run when you log in that launches this script. This ought to do it if you adjust the path in the last argument to the full path of where you saved the big script:

```
powershell -Command "Start-Process -WindowStyle Hidden -FilePath powershell -ArgumentList 'C:\path\to\your\script.ps1'"
```

If you ever need to update the list of places for the various extensions to go, just update the script file. After doing that, you can either log off and back on, or kill and restart the background PowerShell process.

Comment: Ah.   I forgot about ps.   I hate the gui interface for scheduling tasks and I wanted something command line based. This could be it.